# Is there a service/application that will allow a "friend" to retrieve my location from my phone without my involvement?

Tags: gps, geolocation

I'd like to allow my wife to query my location whenever she's curious. There are no trust issues here, so I don't care about acknowledging/approving her "ping" request, whenever she wants to know she can just request my location details.

Is there an app or service that does this? Most of them (understandably) require that the handset owner allow/permit the request, but I'd like this to happen without my involvement (say I'm busy at the office, driving, or getting groceries).

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like [Google Latitude](http://www.google.com/mobile/latitude/) does what you want. Once you opt-in you can then share your location data with your wife, and she should be able to check your location anytime. As far as I know, once you choose share your location data with someone they can retrieve it anytime without having to explicitly request your permission.

Latitude is built into the Google Maps application for Android. You can enable it by going into the application's settings and checking "Enable location sharing", then use the setting right below it ("Manage your friends") to choose who can see your location data.

Comment: Latitude was my first choice/thought but this requires that the ping recipient allow/acknowledge the ping. It is not automatic or seamless.

Comment: @JPAnderson: Have you tried it? I thought you only had to do the approval once, then it would automatically plot your friends on the map for you from then on (I admittedly do not use this myself, so I'm basing this mostly on Google's documentation).

Comment: I use Latitude and I confirm that it allows continuous location visibility.

Comment: Been using Latitude for me and my girlfriend. No problems here.

Answer (score 3):

You could also combine this with some anti-theft solution. E.g. [Wheres My Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alienmanfc6.wheresmyandroid) reacts on "attention words" you set up, and e.g. sends the current location (also by SMS), or turns on the alarm on another "attention word". With your wife knowing (some of) those "attention words", she can get to know where you are (or rather where your device is) -- while at the same time you have some added value. Look for "anti-theft" on the playstore to find more like this, if it sounds useful to you.